# getting a TGT using service principal

Tags: linux, authentication, kerberos

I'm trying to use kerberos authentication (active directory running on windows) for my application on linux machines. I'm able to get a TGT using the 'kinit user' command for the user accounts registered with Active Directory. However when I try to get a TGT using 'kinit servicePrincipal' I'm getting the following error:

*Client not found in kerberos database while getting initial credentials*

The service principals used have been added to one of the user accounts using the 'setspn -s' command.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SPNs are not UPNs and therefore they can't acquire tickets from the Active Directory. They are supposed to accept security contexts only, not initiating them..

Comment: Usually you are right, but service principal can be kinit-ed according to the [specification](https://www.kerberos.org/software/tutorial.html) (see 4.1, Note 1).
kinit -S imap/mbox.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM pippo@EXAMPLE.COM

Comment: The question was specific to Active Directory, therefore I answer it.

Comment: I have tried to get a service ticket from Active Directory and it does work! In this case only the service ticket is placed into the credential cache and no TGT entry can be seen. So try something similar to `kinit -S imap/mbox.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM pippo@EXAMPLE.COM`.

Comment: Does not work for me:
`# KRB5_TRACE=/tmp/out kinit -S host/deblndw024v@AD001.SIEMENS.NET -k  'deblndw024v$'
kinit: KDC reply did not match expectations while getting initial credentials`

Comment: I'm not a Kerberos guru, but IMHO you have to specify the user principal! It is the `pippo@EXAMPLE.COM` in the example. The `-k` can be used if you want to specify the service principal read from a keytab file (more probably on the Application server itself). But here you specified the service principal with the `-S` option.

Comment: Very useful comment from @TrueY, works for me (for example `kinit -S host/host1 user1`)